# How do I alter an object attribute accurately based on an association count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I got a sample class:

```
class Human < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :diseases
  before_save :check_health

  def check_health
    if(diseases.count == 0)
      self.healthy = true
    end
  end
end
```

I want to change the fields of the object before saving it.

The problem:

- `self.diseases` returns the old value of the `diseases` association.
- The new value of `:diseases` can be accessed via `association_cache[:diseases]`, but I don't know how to use `association_cache`. I don't understand which objects are marked for deletion, which objects are new, and which have been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not reload the relation object to get an accurate count? Try this:

```
  def check_health
    healthy = true unless diseases.reload.any?
  end
```

Comment: This do not work as intended. diseases.reload loads the old associations from the db (I need the new ones from association_cache) and somehow it prevents the new items to be saved (really strange).

Comment: fiction, I guess I'm a bit unsure about what you need exactly. `diseases.reload` should give you the number of diseases saved. `diseases.size` will give you a count of what's loaded into memory, and any additional unsaved diseases in the array. It would be helpful if you describe the problem holistically.

Answer (score 0):

At first I think the logic in `#check_health` is totally correct. No need to change it.

The reason you met the problem may be you used it on non-persisted objects, both human and disease.

To solve it, I think the correct approach is to change the `before_save` callback to `after_save` callback. This will make more sense. Also it looks you only need this method for later use after saving, so why not do that?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on still not-persisted objects. I don't think that after_save is good idea, because of the save! needed and possible stack overflow problems

Comment: @fiction, I don't understand why it is bad if save! required, as well as "possible stack overflow problem"